# Object is deformed with spiky artifacts when rendering in Blender cycles 2.8

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I have been noodling around with the blender 2.8 Beta because I just want to get up on the new stuff. I have tried to render this simple model of a sofa I’ve been building and I get these crazy spiky artifacts! 
When I export an OBJ and render it in an old version, 2.79 the sofa looks just fine,  no crazy spiky artifacts. Has anybody else dealt with this in blender 2.8 beta, and what causes it?
I am using cycles.
[image]

Comment: "Suzanne! Have you been jumping on the sofa?!" (Uploading your .blend to [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) will greatly boost your chances of getting help.)

Comment: Could be that your material has a displacement aspect, and it's displacing actual geometry. Make sure the displacment type is set to "bump only"

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project.

Comment: @Dr.Farquaad good ideas!

Comment: @Dr.Farquaad good ideas! Thanks for the input!

Comment: And now I have fixed it once I had a friendly suggestion to help guide my way!